# Avoid backward analysis of HTML in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I am attempting to analyze a single Java file in IntelliJ by selecting Analyze > Inspect Code from the context menu.  Specifically, I am wanting to search for unused methods or fields.  I have used this quite a bit with previous projects.  Unfortunately, my current project has a bunch of HTML and JavaScript code.  It appears that all of those files are being analyzed when I attempt to inspect my Java code.  How do I avoid the inclusion of my HTML code in the backward analysis step?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom scope and exclude *.html and *.js, then when you run inspect code, choose to inspect code only in your custom scope.

Comment: The problem is that the scope, from what I understand, determines which java files to include in the analysis.  I only want to analyze one java file.  I may not be understanding the inspect scope though.